# Applying clipTo path on image in fabric.js incorrectly repositions the image

Tags: fabricjs, clipping

Please take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ktvyk4e/5/

```
    var imgUrl, snapshotCanvas;

    imgUrl = 'http://cdn-development.wecora.com/boards/backgrounds/000/001/388/cover/ocean-background.jpg';

    snapshotCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('snapshotCanvas', {
      backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
      width: 1000,
      height: 1500
    });

    fabric.Image.fromURL(imgUrl, function(img) {
      img.set({
        width: 1000,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        clipTo: function(ctx) {
          return ctx.rect(0, 0, 1000, 400);
        }
      });
      return snapshotCanvas.add(img).renderAll();
    }, {
      crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
    });
```

It's pretty simple.  I'm loading an image and then trying to clip it so that the full width of the canvas but clipped so only the top 400 pixels are showing.  For some reason, the clipTo causes the image to move and resize inexplicably:

[image]

As you can see, when the clipping path is applied the image is repositioned on the canvas inexplicably.  If I remove the clipTo, then the image loads full canvas width no problem (of course its also full height, which we don't want).

I have no idea what is happening here or why this is occuring so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `originX` and `originY` left to `top` and `left` on both the canvas and your image. Also - you don't really need to clip anything to the canvas. The only real use I've found for clipTo was clipping collage images to their bounding shapes. If you want to restrict the image from being dragged above that 400px, I would recommend rendering a rectangle below it (`evented = false`, `selectable = false`) and then clipping to that rectangle.

I put this together without `clipTo` (and changed some numbers so I wasn't scrolling sideways). It renders the image half way down the canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ktvyk4e/6/

Edit:

I dug through some source code to find the `clipByName` method and the two helper methods for finding stuff. I use this for keeping track of collage images and their bounding rectanlges ("images" and "clips"). I store them in an object:

```
imageObjects: { 
    'collage_0': http://some.tld/to/image.ext,
    'collage_1': http://some.tld/to/image2.ext 
}
```

Helper methods for finding either the clip or image:

```
findClipByClipName: function (clipName) {
    var clip = _(canvas.getObjects()).where({ clipFor: clipName }).first();

    return clip;
},

findImageByClipFor: function (clipFor) {
    var image = _(canvas.getObjects()).where({ clipName: clipFor }).first();

    return image;
},
```

Actual clipping method:

```
clipByName: function (ctx) {
    this.setCoords();
    var clipRect, scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1;
    clipRect = collage.findClipByClipName(this.clipName);
    scaleXTo1 = (1 / this.scaleX);
    scaleYTo1 = (1 / this.scaleY);
    ctx.save();

    var ctxLeft, ctxTop;
    ctxLeft = -(this.width / 2) + clipRect.strokeWidth;
    ctxTop = -(this.height / 2) + clipRect.strokeWidth;

    ctx.translate(ctxLeft, ctxTop);

    ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
    ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(
        clipRect.left - this.oCoords.tl.x,
        clipRect.top - this.oCoords.tl.y,
        clipRect.width,
        clipRect.height
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();

    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    }
},
```

And finally adding images to canvas where all of this comes together:

```
var clipName, clip, image;

clipName = helpers.findKeyByValue(url, this.imageObjects);
clip = this.findClipByClipName(clipName);

image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    var collageImage = new fabric.Image(image, $.extend({}, collage.commonImageProps, {
        left: clip.left,
        top: clip.top,
        clipName: clipName,
        clipTo: function (ctx) {
            return _.bind(collage.clipByName, collageImage)(ctx);
        }
    }));

    collage.scaleImagesToClip(collageImage);
    canvas.add(collageImage);
};
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont think you fully understood the use case.  This is a HEADER image (see http://staging.wecora.com/boards/_Mwn5zsfpo1XB7RQpyPa) for an example.  I want the header image to be canvas width but only the top 300 pixels to be visible.  I tried offsetX/Y on canvas and image without effect.  Also, your other solution seems to be overkill for this.  It seems like a fabricjs bug but not sure how to fix.

Comment: @JoshL from that site it doesn't look like you need to use the canvas at all.

Comment: Were using an HTML canvas to create a thumbnail image of the page, which is why we need this functionality.